# Looping through string array, find the two strings with the most overlap and merge them. REPEAT until one string left

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a string array named 'collection' as shown below. I want to loop through the array and find the strings with the most overlap - that is the most same characters in a row. Once I find the two strings I want to append a new string to the array with the concatenation of these two strings and then remove the original strings. The catch is that the concatenation must ignore common characters. For example: 'hello wo' & 'o world' will become 'hello world'. I want to repeat this process until one string is left.

```
let collection = ["all is well", "ell that en", "hat end", "t ends well"];
let longestOverlap = 0;
let longestOverlapChars = '';

for (i = 0 ; i < collection.length ; i++){
     for (j= i+1 ; j < collection.length ; j++){

        findOverlap(collection[i],collection[j]); 
     }
}

function findOverlap(a, b, originalb) {

  if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
    if (longestOverlapChars.length < b.length){      
      longestOverlapChars = b;
      longestOverlap = longestOverlapChars.length;
      console.log(longestOverlapChars, longestOverlap);
    }


    return console.log(a && originalb) ;
  }

  return findOverlap(a, b.substring(0, b.length - 1));
}
```

My results show the 4 outcomes in the console:
ell, hat en, t en, t end.

This shows the instances of overlapping text.

Subsequently 'hat en' is the largest so I want to combine the two strings that have this overlap. So my new string array will look like this:[" all is well", "ell that end", "t ends well"];

There is now 3 strings and I want to repeat this process until I have ["all is well that ends well'].

Can anyone give me some direction with my code? Also, any coding tips will be helpful. Trying to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it could work:

```js
/*
 * findOverlap: 
 *   "merge" two strings, where the overlapping part is not repeated.
 * Input: 
 *   a, b: the strings to "merge"
 *   retry: this is only used by the internal call. It serves to execute the
 *      function a second time with the two strings in reversed positions
 * Returns:
 *   The merged string. If there is no overlap found, then just join the two
 * Examples:
 *   findOverlap("abcdef", "defghi") === "abcdefghi"
 *   findOverlap("aaa", "zzz") === "aaazzz"
 */
function findOverlap(a, b, retry = true) {
    // If one of the two strings is empty, return the other one. This ensures
    //    that empty strings in the collection do not influence the result.
    if (!a || !b) return a || b;
    // Find the position in a, of the first character of b
    let i = a.indexOf(b[0]);
    while (i > -1) { // As long as there is such an occurrence...
        // Calculate what the size of the overlapping part would be:
        //    This is either the size of the remaining part of a, or
        //    the size of b, when it is a real substring of a:
        let size = Math.min(a.length - i, b.length);
        // See if we have an overlap at this position:
        if (a.slice(i).slice(0, size) === b.slice(0, size)) {
            // Yes! Include the "overflowing" part of b:
            return a + b.slice(size);
        }
        // No match. Try a next position:
        i = a.indexOf(b[0], i+1);
    }
    // The start of b does not overlap with the end of a, so try
    //     the opposite:
    if (retry) return findOverlap(b, a, false); // reversed args
    // If this was already the reversed case, then just concatenate
    return b+a; // Reverse again
}

/*
 * findLongestOverlap: 
 *   find information about the two strings that have the longest overlap.
 * Input: 
 *   collection: an array of strings
 * Returns:
 *   An object with 4 properties:
 *      merged: the merged string, not repeating the overlapping part
 *      i, j: the two indexes in the collection of the contributing strings 
 *      overlapSize: number of characters that are part of the overlap
 * Example:
 *   findLongestOverlap(["abcdef", "defghi", "cdefg"]) returns: 
 *     { merged: "abcdefg", i: 0, j: 2, overlapSize: 4 }
 */
function findLongestOverlap(collection) {
    // Initialise the "best" overlap we have so far (we don't have any yet)
    let longest = { overlapSize: -1 };
    // Iterate all pairs from the collection:
    for (let j = 1; j < collection.length; j++) {
        let b = collection[j];
        for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            let a = collection[i];
            const merged = findOverlap(a, b);
            // Derive the size of the overlap from the merged string:
            const overlapSize = a.length + b.length - merged.length;
            // Did we improve?
            if (overlapSize > longest.overlapSize) {
                // Yes! So keep track of all info we need:
                longest = { merged, i, j, overlapSize };
            }
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

/*
 * reduceToOne: 
 *   merge a series of strings, merging via the greatest overlaps first.
 * Input: 
 *   any number of arguments: all strings
 * Returns:
 *   A single string, which represents the merge
 */
function reduceToOne(...collection) { // Grab all arguments as an array
    // Repeat until the collection is reduced to one element
    for (let i = collection.length; --i; ) {
        // Get information from best possible pair-merge:
        const { merged, i, j } = findLongestOverlap(collection);
        // Remove the original two strings having the longest overlap
        collection.splice(j, 1);
        collection.splice(i, 1);
        // Add the merged string
        collection.push(merged);
    }
    // Return the single string that remains
    return collection[0];
}

// Example run:
let collection = ["all is well", "ell that en", "hat end", "t ends well"];
const result = reduceToOne(...collection); // Spread the array as individual arguments

console.log(result);
```

Comment on your code:

- Avoid modifying variables in a function that are not local variables. So in your case the actions on `longestOverlapChars` and `longestOverlap` violate this best practice.
- The function `findOverlap` works fine when the end of `a` overlaps with the start of `b`, but it will fail to find the overlap if the *end* of `b` overlaps with the *start* of `a`.

Comment: Wow thanks. This is great. Would you be able to leave a few more comments on the code so I know what each line is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function which get the obvelapping lenght, the new string anf the indices of the matching string and filter later the maximum overlapping information, filter the collecttion and add the new string to the collection.

```js
function findOverlap(a, b) {

    function partSubs(a, b, pos) {
        var i = b.length;
        do {
            if (i && a.endsWith(b.slice(0, i))) return [i, a + b.slice(i), pos];
        } while (i--)
    }

    // check full sub
    if (a.includes(b)) return [Infinity, a, pos];
    if (b.includes(a)) return [Infinity, b, pos];

    // get partSubs
    var temp = [partSubs(a, b, [i, j]), partSubs(b, a, [j, i])];
    if (temp[0] && temp[1]) return temp[0][0] > temp[1][0] ? temp[0] : temp[1];
    return temp[0] || temp[1];
}

var collection = ["all is well", "ell that en", "hat end", "t ends well"],
    overlap,
    i, j,
    longest;

while (collection.length > 1) {
    overlap = [];
    for (i = 0; i < collection.length - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < collection.length; j++)
            overlap.push(findOverlap(collection[i], collection[j]));

    longest = overlap.reduce((a, b) => a && b ? a[0] > b[0] ? a : b : a || b);
    collection = collection.filter((_, i) => !longest[2].includes(i));
    collection.push(longest[1]);
}

console.log(collection);
```